# azure keyvault SLA and service availability

Tags: azure, high-availability

If you read the SLA for Azure key vault it's SLA is stated to 99.9 %.

But should this not mean that if you build a applikation that uses keyvault for all it's secred you would be caped at 99.9 SLA due to the fact that the applikation cant work without passwords, connectionstrings etc?

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that you don't want to take a **runtime** dependency on Key Vault. Make it a **deploy-time** dependency to acquire the connection strings and store them in memory in your application during deployment.

Unless you don't care about availability being no better than 99.9% of a response within 5 seconds of course (which may be the case for some applications).

Answer (score 0):

> But should this not mean that if you build a applikation that uses
>   keyvault for all it's secred you would be caped at 99.9 SLA due to the
>   fact that the applikation cant work without passwords,
>   connectionstrings etc?

Usually, we calculate the SLA in this way.

But in Azure, we calculate the SLA for different Azure services in different way, there are calculated individually. So the application will **not** be caped at 99.9 SLA.

Comment: Hmm i do  not fully understand, how can i achive a higher SLA. then the lowest SLA of any component in my application?

Comment: Jason is talking about legal contract values: using azurevault does not lower the sla on other azure services to 99.9 %.  you are correct though: you can not expect your complete service to work with a higher than 99.9% SLA if the application relies exclusively on azurevault for authentication data.

Comment: @Bjorne If you use Azure service to deploy your application, this service has a default SLA. To get a higher SLA, we can use traffic manager or others. For example, deploy a web application, we can deploy two services in different regions, and use traffic manager to achieve high availability.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's complicated.
Firstly, if your application caches stuff that you read from the key vault then you will have some resilience to outages. I suspect that's why key vault only has 99.9.

On the other hand, your app probably also relies on other services, such as web hosting, databases etc, so the aggregate theoretical SLA is the different SLAs multiplied, ie. 0.999 * 0.9997 * ... etc.
Whether that is good enough for you depends on your needs.

It is possible to improve this by doubling up on every thing and handling additional failovers in your app - but it gets complicated and expensive very quickly; it's a business decision, not a technical decision.